# AWS DynamoDB : Unmarshalliing BatchGetItem response

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-go

I am using GO SDK and using the DynamnoDB `BatchGetItem` API.

I saw this code example -

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/service/dynamodb/examples_test.go

Is there any other code example which shows unmarshalling of the response from the `BatchGetItem` API?

Comment: The response is just json. What’s wrong with that example?

Answer (score 4):

Let me share piece of the code. The key to understand it is that when you send GetBatchItem request to dynamodb, you specify map of table names and keys for that table, so response you get is a map of tables names and matched items

```
placeIDs := []string { "london_123", "sanfran_15", "moscow_9" }

type Place {
    ID string `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
}

mapOfAttrKeys := []map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{}

for _, place := range placeIDs {
    mapOfAttrKeys = append(mapOfAttrKeys, map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        "id": &dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            S: aws.String(place),
        },
        "attr": &dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            S: aws.String("place"),
        },
    })
}

input := &dynamodb.BatchGetItemInput{
    RequestItems: map[string]*dynamodb.KeysAndAttributes{
        tableName: &dynamodb.KeysAndAttributes{
            Keys: mapOfAttrKeys,
        },
    },
}

batch, err := db.BatchGetItem(input)

if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Errorf("batch load of places failed, err: %w", err))
}

for _, table := range batch.Responses {
    for _, item := range table {
        var place Place

        err = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(item, &place)

        if err != nil {
            panic(fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshall place from dynamodb response, err: %w", err))
        }

        places = append(places, place)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you initially define `places`? Would it be: `places := []Place{}` just before the outer `for _, table` loop?

Answer (score 0):

These are quite old question and answer but they have been very useful, thanks to both the TP @dattatray and @itmeze

Nevertheless, today Amazon advises new implementation to be used, AWS SDK for Go V2, where the same stuff can be implemented in more concise and expressive way.

```go
    import (
        "context"
        "fmt"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/attributevalue"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb/types"
    )

    type Place struct {
        ID string `dynamodbav:"id" json:"id"`
        Name string `dynamodbav:"name" json:"name"`
        Description string `dynamodbav:"description" json:"description"`
    }


    // define your context and DynamoDB client
    var ctx context.Context
    var db dynamodb.Client
    

    placeIDs := []string { "london_123", "sanfran_15", "moscow_9" }
    tableName := "Places"

    //marshall and collect into a slice the keys to be queried
    var requests types.KeysAndAttributes
    for _, place := range placeIDs {
        key := struct {
            Name string `dynamodbav:"name" json:"name"`
        } {Name: place}
        item, err := attributevalue.MarshalMap(key)
        if err != nil {
            panic(fmt.Errorf("failed to marshal key %s, err: %w", place, err))
        }
        requests.Keys = append(requests.Keys, item)
    }

    //prepare and issue `BatchGetItem` request
    batch := make(map[string]types.KeysAndAttributes)
    batch[tableName] = requests
    op, err := db.BatchGetItem(ctx, &dynamodb.BatchGetItemInput{
        RequestItems: batch,
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("couldn't send a batch of items to dynamo DB %w", err))
    }

    //here we collect the keys for which we didn't get results
    //basically they can be later passed to retry BatchGetItem call
    var missingKeys []map[string]types.AttributeValue
    if missing, ok := op.UnprocessedKeys[tableName]; ok {
        copy(missingKeys, missing.Keys)
    }

    //collecting the results into the slice
    var resultItems []Place
    for _, items := range op.Responses {
        var unmarshaledItems []Place
        if err := attributevalue.UnmarshalListOfMaps(items, unmarshaledItems); err != nil {
            panic(fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal item, err: %w", err))
        }
        resultItems = append(resultItems, unmarshaledItems...)
    }
```